# How can `setuptools` `dependency_links` be used with the latest master branch of a Git repository?

Tags: pip, setuptools

I want to be able to `pip install` a package that installs a dependency package from GitHub. I want the version of that dependency package it installs to be the latest code in the master branch of the repository (i.e. I am not referencing a release of the package) (and there is a different version of the package for Python 2 and for Python 3). When I attempt to do this, the dependency is ignored. How can I get the dependency to be picked up and installed?

In `setup.py` I have lines like the following:

```
    dependency_links = [
                       "git+https://github.com/veox/python2-krakenex.git;python_version<'3.0'",
                       "git+https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex.git;python_version>='3.0'",
                       ],
```

When I run `pip`, I do it using commands of the following form:

```
sudo pip install package_name --upgrade --process-dependency-links
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. `dependency_links` aren't versioned, they're simple a list of URLs for packages listed in `install_requires`; those packages could be versioned but not in your case — you're trying to provide 2 URLs for one package which would confuse `pip`.

Perhaps you could rename one of the packages and provide package names
in the URLs:

```
install_requires=[
    'krakenex;python_version<3',
    'krakenex3;python_version>=3',
],
dependency_links = [
    "git+https://github.com/veox/python2-krakenex.git#egg=krakenex;python_version<'3.0'",
    "git+https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex.git#egg=krakenex3;python_version>='3.0'",
],
```